# Quando utilizar parâmetros opcionais acima de overloading e vice-versa?

Tags: c#, .net, parâmetros

Um parâmetro opcional no C# é declarado da seguinte forma (veja o parâmetro `y`):

```
public void DoFoo(String x, String y = "") { ... }
```

Em muitos casos, essa *feature* pode ser substituida pelo *overload* da assinatura do método

```
public void DoFoo(String x) { ... }
public void DoFoo(String x, String y) { ... }
```

Quando a melhor opção seria usar *overloading* acima de um parâmetro opcional e vice-versa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Limitações técnicas**

Expor métodos com parâmetros opcionais como APIs para outras linguagens que não suportam esta funcionalidade gera problemas, neste caso sobrecarga de métodos é o recomendável.

Operações com *reflection* também apresentam incompatibilidade com parâmetros opcionais.

**Funcionalidade**

Seu método faz a mesma coisa independentemente dos parâmetros?
Se sim, use parâmetros opcionais, se não use sobrecarga de métodos. Funcionalidades diferentes devem estar em métodos diferentes.

Tirando as limitações técnicas e funcionalidade, os próximos pontos são ***subjetivos***, ou seja, é questão de preferência, gosto e alinhamento com seu time/equipe em relação ao estilo de código empregado:

**Parâmetros opcionais = Menos código**

*Sobrecarga de método:*

```
public void Method(string str1)
{
   // ...
}

public void Method(string str1, string str2)
{
   // ...
}
```

*Parâmetros opcionais:*

```
public void Method(string str1, string str2 = null)
{
   // ...
}
```

No exemplo acima, apenas um método é necessário, diminuindo significativamente a quantidade de código. Consequentemente haverá menos documentação `XML`.

**Parâmetros opcionais = Intellisense mais conciso**

Com parâmetros opcionais, o Intellisense do VS exibe o método em uma linha só com os parâmetros opcionais:

[image: OP]

Com sobrecarga de método, você tem que navegar por cada método para achar o que você deseja:

[image: OL1]
[image: OL2]
[image: OL3]

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132010/c-sharp-optional-parameters-or-method-overload)

Answer (score 1):

O uso dos parâmetros opcionais delegam à lógica da função como serão feitas as operações internas, não deixando a chamada da função decidir qual será o comportamento e uso desses parâmetros.

Em uma função que possui outras sobrecargas, o uso dos parâmetros são explicitados em sua chamada, dando uma noção básica do que será feito em sua lógica interna. Isso possibilita a quem utilizar essa função decidir qual seria a melhor realização de determinada tarefa.